# Laravel queue worker on AWS is not finding jobs

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-aurora, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have a Laravel(v-5.3.31) hosted on AWS ec2 instance(let's call it A). Database is on another AWS AURORA instance (lets call it B).

I have followed all the steps to create a queue. When I create a job through my Laravel application I am able to see the job in **Jobs** table. but when I create queue worker using command on A `php artisan queue:work --once`  it just returns. it does not process any job.

In my job I am creating a new database on AURORA DB (B). Code is below -

```
public static function createDB($master_id)
    {
        $dbName = 'db_id_'.$master_id;

        DB::connection('AURORA')->statement('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.$dbName);
    }
```

Some findings :
1. If I execute same steps from my local system, it is working.
2. If I remove code of db creation from JOB, line no 2. It works, means db creation is creating problem.

I am not able to find the reason, can any one give some hint ...